# Bullet passed by my head

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

> The bullet passed by my head by a difference of a few inches.

I am trying to say that somebody fire a bullet at you that barely missed your head? Or Somebody fire a bullet that nearly hit me in the head. But it missed my head by a few inches. Would it be correct to say sentence above, to describe the situation?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

> The bullet missed my head by only a few inches.

Comment: Does my sentence mean the same as yours or it is totally incorrect?

Comment: Your sentence using 'difference' is not idiomatic. You _could_ say 'the bullet passed [only] a few inches from my head'.

Comment: Usually, 'difference' compares two things, and there is no comparison in your sentence.  Rather, your sentence is 'absolute' in that it talks about the actual distance.  For example, you might use 'distance' like this:  "The distance between the bullet and my head was less than three inches."  However, I prefer the the above myself.  Alan.